# Exception firing destroy event from native

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, native

I've downloaded PhoneGap and tried it. It works well with some html pages + js script. 
 However, I have an issue while trying to access to my "full" application, with all the javascript and html pages...

The error is the following :

```
The connection to the server was unsuccessful. 
 (javascript: 
 try{ 
 cordova.require('cordova/channel').onDestroy.fire(); 
 } catch(e) { 
 console.log('exception firing destroy event from native'); 
 };)
```

Any idea why it's happening?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you have a similar issue to this question: [Phonegap cordova 2.7.0 error when pausing app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424578/phonegap-cordova-2-7-0-error-when-pausing-app)

I had the same problem, and like they suggested, switching back to version 2.4 fixed it.

I think I've found the change that was included in 2.5, which caused the problem. I've added a comment at the affected line here:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/cb192056f82e051a05bbda8b09ac01a118c39838

Hopefully someone who works on Cordova will get it fixed soon.

Comment: Kudos to you for taking the time to find, fix and submit the fix.  Hope they incorporate your fix soon.  In the meantime, I'm gonna try using 2.4