# Phonegap cordova 2.7.0 error when pausing app

Tags: cordova, timeout

I've created a clean cordova 2.7.0 project by using the phonegap tool "create"
(create project_folder package_name project_name) 
and I've deployed the app to my Nexus 4 (androind 4.2.2). 
No code has been written.

The app has been executed with no errors because it has shown the phonegap logo and "apache cordova device is ready".
The problem is that when I tap the standard android right button(which shows recent running apps) I see in the eclipse LogCat that an error ocurrs:

```
05-07 18:29:54.957: D/webviewglue(24649): nativeDestroy view: 0x731f4738
05-07 18:30:10.163: D/DroidGap(24649): Paused the application!
05-07 18:30:10.163: D/CordovaWebView(24649): Handle the pause
05-07 18:30:10.453: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24649): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-07 18:30:10.743: D/DroidGap(24649): onDestroy()
05-07 18:30:10.743: D/CordovaWebView(24649): >>> loadUrl(javascript:try{cordova.require('cordova/channel').onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');};)
05-07 18:30:10.743: D/PluginManager(24649): init()
05-07 18:30:10.753: D/CordovaWebView(24649): >>> loadUrlNow()
05-07 18:30:30.765: E/CordovaWebView(24649): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
05-07 18:30:30.765: D/Cordova(24649): CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful. URL=javascript:try{cordova.require('cordova/channel').onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');};
05-07 18:30:30.765: D/DroidGap(24649): onMessage(onReceivedError,{"errorCode":-6,"url":"javascript:try{cordova.require('cordova\/channel').onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');};","description":"The connection to the server was unsuccessful."})
```

After this error I tap the app from the list and a popup titled "Application Error" appears containing exactly this message:

"**The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (javascript:try{cordova.require('cordova/channel').onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');};)**"

This behavior happens always (sometimes it requires to pause the app by using the recent apps list button twice).

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE: As suggested by Romain Braun by using 2.4.0 the error does not occur.**

Comment: Would you be ok to downgrade to 2.4 ?

Comment: Apparently this bug appeared after Cordova2.5

Comment: As suggested by @RomainBraun  by using 2.4.0 the error does not occur. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It might be a good idea to report the bug to the phonegap team though. I saw you were not the only one to get this bug, yet no one found a solution.

Comment: I wrote this as an answer, so the question doesn't stay "unanswered". If you could validate it, please :)

Comment: I could not reproduce on nexus 7 running 4.2.2....

Comment: @MBillau I reproduced it in a clean app as described in the post and also by migrating a cordova app from 1.9.0 to 2.7.0. By the way did you tried to perform the operation several times?

Comment: Yes, correct in a clean app. I built the nightly version from github and tested with that, did you use the packaged download from phonegap.com? I tired a bunch of times to generate. Will try again today on different versions of Android and with the build...if this is a bug it should be filed but I didn't see anything in JIRA...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bug appeared after the release of Cordova 2.5

Yet no one has found a solution.

I'd recommend reporting the bug to the phonegap team, and downgrading your Cordova version to 2.4 if it is possible.

Comment: I've tried so many solutions, but nothing worked as far. thanks your suggestion. It looks good so far

Comment: Think I found the problem, added comment to line in [this commit](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/cb192056f82e051a05bbda8b09ac01a118c39838) - hopefully someone will fix it soon :)

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the load timeout value in the onCreate method of your
Java class that extends DroidGap:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was also fixed with when I used 2.4, but I decided to post it as an issue on their issue tracker:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3749

Apparently for me it happened because I had removed a few lines in my manifest, because I was targeting android-10, but I should have just targeted android-17 since phonegap itself works for android-10, without me having to target it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this annoying issue until I realized I was using the wrong Cordova.js file. Changed it and the problem is gone. Im using phonegap 2.7.

Comment: can you provide more details? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is very broad and symptomatic of a number of issues.I have got it when I was overriding the onPageFinished and onPageStarted methods on my webview client and forgot to call super.onPageFinished(view, url) for example.

Note that timeouts are "cleared" on these methods:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java#L299

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with Cordova 2.5 and reverted back to 2.4. I've recently tried 2.9 and I'm no longer getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont use webview.handlePause(false) in Activity's onPause() method, but only use webview.handleDestroy() in Activity's onDestroy() method instead.

It happens when user re-open activity , and we fixed it in that way in our app.

Cordova-2.5.jar