# Phonegap Screen-orientation plugin update for 2.7.0 or 2.8.0

Tags: eclipse, cordova, orientation

Is there anybody out there, who knows how to fix [this](https://github.com/their/pg-plugin-screen-orientation) plugin to work with the newest cordova/phonegap version?

I have no idea how i can fix the errors in eclipse and i really need a method to change orientation for several pages in my phonegap app!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the following changes:

**ScreenOrientation.java**

Replace with this:

```
package com.tsukurusha.phonegap.plugins;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;

public class ScreenOrientation extends CordovaPlugin {
    // Refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation
    private static final String UNSPECIFIED = "unspecified";
    private static final String LANDSCAPE = "landscape";
    private static final String PORTRAIT = "portrait";
    private static final String USER = "user";
    private static final String BEHIND = "behind";
    private static final String SENSOR = "sensor";
    private static final String NOSENSOR = "nosensor";
    private static final String SENSOR_LANDSCAPE = "sensorLandscape";
    private static final String SENSOR_PORTRAIT = "sensorPortrait";
    private static final String REVERSE_LANDSCAPE = "reverseLandscape";
    private static final String REVERSE_PORTRAIT = "reversePortrait";
    private static final String FULL_SENSOR = "fullSensor";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("set")) {
            String orientation = args.optString(0);     
            Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
            if (orientation.equals(UNSPECIFIED)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
            } else if (orientation.equals(LANDSCAPE)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (orientation.equals(PORTRAIT)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (orientation.equals(USER)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
            } else if (orientation.equals(BEHIND)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_BEHIND);
            } else if (orientation.equals(SENSOR)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
            } else if (orientation.equals(NOSENSOR)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
            } else if (orientation.equals(SENSOR_LANDSCAPE)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (orientation.equals(SENSOR_PORTRAIT)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (orientation.equals(REVERSE_LANDSCAPE)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (orientation.equals(REVERSE_PORTRAIT)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (orientation.equals(FULL_SENSOR)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
            }
            callbackContext.success();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }       
    }
}
```

**pg-plugin-screen-orientation.js**

Replace with this:

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/screenorientation", function(require, exports, module) {
    var exec = require('cordova/exec');    
    var ScreenOrientation = function() {};    
    ScreenOrientation.prototype.set = function(str, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        exec(successCallback,
    errorCallback,
    'ScreenOrientation',
    'set',
    [str]);
    };        
    var screenorientation = new ScreenOrientation();
    module.exports = screenorientation;
});
```

Then you can replace **sample.html** with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ScreenOrientation PhoneGap Plugin Sample</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="pg-plugin-screen-orientation.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setOrientation(type){
                cordova.require('cordova/plugin/screenorientation').set(
                    type,
                    function() {
                        console.log("Successfully set "+type);
                    },
                    function() {
                        console.error("Failed to set "+type);
                    }
                );
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ScreenOrientation PhoneGap Plugin Sample</h1>
        <input type="button" onclick="setOrientation('landscape');" value="Landscape" />
        <input type="button" onclick="setOrientation('portrait');" value="Portrait" />
        <input type="button" onclick="setOrientation('sensorLandscape');" value="Sensor Landscape" />
        <input type="button" onclick="setOrientation('sensorPortrait');" value="Sensor Portrait" />
        <input type="button" onclick="setOrientation('reverseLandscape');" value="Reverse Landscape" />
        <input type="button" onclick="setOrientation('reversePortrait');" value="Reverse Portrait" />
        <input type="button" onclick="setOrientation('fullSensor');" value="Full Sensor" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I've put this together as an Eclipse project - you can download it and the resulting APK [here](http://ge.tt/1sn9b9j/v/0)

Note: You might want downgrade from Cordova 2.8.0 to Cordova 2.4.0 until issues with pausing the app in Cordova 2.5.0+ have been resolved - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424578/phonegap-cordova-2-7-0-error-when-pausing-app)

Comment: What about cordova 3.0.0, any changes ?

Comment: I'm using cordova 3.00 and getting failed to set message ??

Comment: It probably needs updating for use with cordova 3

Comment: You can probably update it yourself - it shouldn't need much of a tweak. I'm travelling at the moment so not got much time, but I'll be back home in a couple of days so if you've not got it working by then I'll see if I can post an updated version for you :-)

Comment: The plugin is now compatible with Phonegap 3 https://github.com/their/pg-plugin-screen-orientation/pull/8