# setting portrait or landscape programmatically in phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to run the phonegap application in portrait mode for mobile phones and portrait & landscape modefor the tablets. How can we set the screen modes programatically in the phonegap application.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this Phonegap screen orientation plugin](https://github.com/their/pg-plugin-screen-orientation). The version in GitHub doesn't work with latest versions of Cordova but I posted updated code in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049474/phonegap-screen-orientation-plugin-update-for-2-7-0-or-2-8-0/17054510#17054510).
You can still download my Eclipse project containing the updated plugin [from here](http://ge.tt/1sn9b9j/v/0).

Then in your app you just need to determine if device is a tablet or phone using the Device API in phonegap and call the appropriate plugin function.