# Disable orientation change for only specific page

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an application with jquerymobile. I want to disable my landscape orientation for only main page not for others. Are there any commands to do this for pages separately instead of manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you can use [this screen orientation Phonegap plugin](https://github.com/their/pg-plugin-screen-orientation) in your main page. I've updated the code to be compatible with Phonegap 2.8.0 - you can find the source code in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049474/phonegap-screen-orientation-plugin-update-for-2-7-0-or-2-8-0/17054510#17054510) as well my Eclipse project and resulting APK.

There's an equivalent iOS plugin [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ScreenOrientation) but I haven't used it and it may need updating for use with the most recent versions of Phonegap.