# Phonegap update Screen-orientation plugin for cordova 3.0.0

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, cordova-3

Screen-orientation plugin for Android didn't work for Cordova 3.0.0,
Also I'm tried this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049474/phonegap-screen-orientation-plugin-update-for-2-7-0-or-2-8-0) and nothing happend.

Any help ?